# writing hessian service

Tags: spring, maven, hessian

I am new to Spring and Hessian and never used them before.

I want to write a small Hello World Program which clearly shows how this service works.

I am using Maven for list project details and dependencies.

The resources for hessian available online are not complete step-by-step guide.

would appreciate if I get help form someone who has worked writing hessian services

Answer (score 7):

The steps for implementing a Hessian-callable service are:

- Create a Java interface defining methods to be called by clients.
- Write a Java class implementing this interface.
- Configure a servlet to handle HTTP Hessian service requests.
- Configure a [HessianServiceExporter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/remoting/caucho/HessianServiceExporter.html) to handle Hessian service requests from the servlet by delegating service calls to the Java class implementing this interface.

Let's go through an example.  Create a Java interface:

```
public interface EchoService {
    String echoString(String value);
}
```

Write a Java class implementing this interface:

```
public class EchoServiceImpl implements EchoService {
    public String echoString(String value) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

In the `web.xml` file, configure a servlet:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>/EchoService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>/EchoService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/remoting/EchoService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Configure an instance of the service class in the Spring application context:

```
<bean id="echoService" class="com.example.echo.EchoServiceImpl"/>
```

Configure the exporter in the Spring application context.  The bean name must match the servlet name.

```
<bean
    name="/EchoService"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter">
  <property name="service" ref="echoService"/>
  <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.example.echo.EchoService"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: See my answer please for a test case.

Answer (score 4):

The client has to create a proxy of the remote interface. You could simply write a JUnit-Test:

```
HessianProxyFactory proxyFactory = new HessianProxyFactory();
        proxyFactory.setHessian2Reply(false);
        proxyFactory.setHessian2Request(false);
        com.example.echo.EchoService service = proxyFactory.create(
                com.example.echo.EchoService, "http://localhost:8080/<optional-context/>remoting/EchoService");

Assert.equals(service.echoString("test"), "test");
```

Comment: why setHessian2Reply(false), setHessian2Request(false)?

Answer (score 0):

The question is very old and the most voted answer became obsolete: Spring's `HessianServiceExporter` was deprecated in Spring 5.3 and removed in Spring 6.

Currently the steps for implementing a Hessian-callable service are:

1. Create a Java interface defining methods to be called by clients.
2. Write a Java class implementing this interface.
3. Extend `HessianServlet` to implement the same interface and delegate the business logic to the Java class created at step #2 (implementing this logic directly in the servlet is possible but not recommended).
4. Use Spring's `ServletRegistrationBean` to enable the servlet.

[hessian-demo](https://github.com/pnavato/hessian-demo) provides a working example of a Hessian-based web service in a Spring Boot application without `HessianServiceExporter`. You can even use the Jakarta-based Spring Boot 3.