# Hessian exclude Fields

Tags: java, spring, hessian

Following [writing hessian serivce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753852/writing-hessian-serivce) I have setup Hessian webservice in my spring application and its working.

Using org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter - SpringFramework 3.1, Hessian 4.0.1,

```
public interface RetailService {
    List<User> getUserList();
}

@Component
public class RetailServiceImpl implements RetailService {
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        List<User> list=//get from db
        return list;
    }
}

class User{
    String name,otherFields;

    //Exclude this from serialization
    Role role;
}
```

How to exclude some fields from getting serialized.
I could write a wrapper/inherited class excluding Role ,But I prefer something simple(like annotation) using the existing class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transient` - a keyword which prevents the field from serialization :

```
transient Role role;
```

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables) for more.

Comment: Working,But is there anything else specify to hessian so that role is available for normal serialization by other modules?